# Need details of Request body parameters in "Create an Ad" Campaign API

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Endpoint - /a/ads-management/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/ads

We are trying to utilize Ads API in our product.  Below is the example JSON given in the docs. https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/api-reference/v0/ads/management/#/ads/post_a_ads_management_api_v0_institutions__institutionId__ads

```
{
  "title": "string",
  "templateId": "string",
  "active": true,
  "values": [
    {
      "id": {
        "blockName": "string",
        "fieldName": "string"
      },
      "value": {
        "value": "string"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Questions**

Can you explain what is "values" array ?
What should we pass in "id", "blockName", "fieldName", "value" that are being used inside values array.?
Can you provide example values for all?

We went through the docs, but were not able to find explanation and examples for these fields.

Answer (score 0):

`values` will be an array of **adValue** objects. We are working on updating our docs to provide the defined adValue values that you can use.

I will update this answer when the documentation updates are published.

Comment: Hi Sam, Any update on the documentation

Comment: What is an adValue Object ? How do we use it ? Where can we find references of it ?

Comment: Any updates on the documentation ?